# update part of the the field in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
UPDATE record 
SET recordId = replace(recordId, substr(recordId, 6, 3), '000'), 
WHERE recordId LIKE '%001'
```

**Errors**

It seems that `recordId = replace(recordId, substr(recordId, 6, 3), '000')` is not allowed in `UPDATE`.

How to do this?

Comment: So what errors did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove comma `,` before `where`

```
 UPDATE record SET recordId = replace(recordId, substr(recordId, 6, 3), '000')
 WHERE recordId LIKE '%001'
```

Next time don't forget to put error message, please. We don't know what is your problem. I only sow that there is redundant comma by accident.